# In a additive tensor category, End(1) ,where 1 is a unit object, is a commutative ring

Tags: category-theory, additive-categories

I am reading Tannakian categories by Deligne and Milne. The question is this :

Let (C,#) is an additive tensor category and (1,e) is an identity object then R= End(1) which acts on each object of X, via l: X ~ 1#X ( ~ means isomorphism). The action of R on X commutes with endomorphism of X , so R is commutative.

I know how to show that it is a ring but I don’t figure out why action of R on X commutes with endomorphism of X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that $(X,Y)\mapsto X\otimes Y$ is a functor. We let an endomorphism of $X$ act on $X\otimes Y$ as $a\otimes 1$. Then it is clear that the actions of $End(X)$ and $End(Y)$ on $X\otimes Y$ commute. In particular, the actions of $End(1)$ and $End(X)$ on $1\otimes X$ (hence also on $X$) commute.